# javascript cannot map array of objects with nested values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mapping, javascript-objects

Trying to map array of objects with values nested in child objects structure like:

```
const objs = [{
        "B": {
            "value": 1,
        },
        "D": {
            "value": "45"
        },
        "E": {
            "value": "234"
        },
        "A": {
            "value": "543"
        },
        "C": {
            "value": "250"
        }
    },...]
```

to the structure like:

```
[
  { name: 'B', value: 1 }, 
  { name: 'D', value: '45' }, 
  { name: 'E', value: '234' }, 
  { name: 'A', value: '543' },
  { name: 'C', value: '250' }
]
```

and the result of the mapping is `undefined`

```
const mapped = objs.map((key, index) => {
  Object.keys(key).map(el => ({
    name: el
  }))
})
```

Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a6unq3)

Comment: `return` is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `return` statement and `value` property definition.

Besides you may want to use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to avoid a nested array in the result:

```js
const objs = [{
    "B": {
        "value": 1,
    },
    "D": {
        "value": "45"
    },
    "E": {
        "value": "234"
    },
    "A": {
        "value": "543"
    },
    "C": {
        "value": "250"
    }
}]

const mapped = objs.flatMap((key, index) => {
    return Object.keys(key).map(el => ({
        name: el,
        value: key[el].value
    }))
})

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Great example. Is there a way to keep order of the elements through the iteration as in the example?

Comment: Thanks! Is the order of objects in result different from the order of keys? On my side it appear to be the same (B, D, E, A, C).

Answer (score 4):

You should operate on objs[0], not objs, because it is an array of one object, not array of objects.

```
let array = []
for(let object in objs[0]){
array.push({
"name": object,
"value": objs[0][object].value
})
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I didn't add whole data structure (just three dots), there are array of objects like in the example on the stackblitz.

Answer (score 3):

`return` is missing in `Object.keys`. As well instead of `Object.keys` use `Object.entries` to get `key` and `value`.

```js
const objs = [{
  "B": {
    "value": 1,
  },
  "D": {
    "value": "45"
  },
  "E": {
    "value": "234"
  },
  "A": {
    "value": "543"
  },
  "C": {
    "value": "250"
  }
}];
const mapped = objs.map((key, _) => {
  return Object.entries((key)).map(([name, {
    value
  }]) => ({
    name,
    value
  }))
}).flat();

console.log(mapped);
```