# Map array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Please read carefully the question, this is not a duplicate of:

- [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript-6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)
- [javascript cannot map array of objects with nested values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056649/javascript-cannot-map-array-of-objects-with-nested-values)
- [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)
- [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848)
- [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)
- [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848)

  ---

Let's consider the following array of object:

```
var obj = [{ 'key1' : 'value1' }, { 'key2' : 'value2' }];
```

I would like to map the array to get keys and values for each object. Something like:

```
obj.map((key, val) => console.log(key, val));
```

I already try many stuff like `Object.entries(obj)` but it always results in complicated solution with many brackets like `Object.entries(obj)[0][1]`

**Is there a simple, nice and efficient way to map an array of object? Note I need key and value for each object**

Comment: `objs.flatMap(Object.entries)` should do?

Comment: What is the expected output value, **to what** do you want to map the array of objects? Your "something like" only does log the keys and values, which is trivial and does not need `map`. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I want to create a HTTP request like key1=value1&key2=value2, but I already know how to do that, I just have difficulties accessing the object keys and values.

Comment: Please show your code then. It seems you have no problem with iterating through the array, but just getting key and value from the object? The solution to that would be to use a less weird input format - why an array of single-property objects instead of one object with multiple properties that you could simply enumerate?

Comment: @Fifi what final result are you looking for? Is your expected result an array, or a single obj, and what values are in it?

Comment: The answer to the question as given ("*simple, nice and efficient way to map an array of object?*") is `arrayOfObjects.map(object => /* something */)`. But that doesn't seem to be what you're after, so please ask your *actual* question.

Comment: `map(object => /* something */)` ok, how do you access keys ?

Comment: @Fifi `.map` gives you back an array... but are you looking for an array as a result?

Comment: @Fifi Just like you [always access the keys of an object, i.e. `for (const key in object)` or `Object.keys(object)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684672/1048572), but that has nothing to do with the `map` around it.

Comment: @nopole, yes, I'm looking for an array. If you want to know, I'm using .join(&) on the array to get the final string.

Comment: @Fifi you are trying to use `.map` to get a string `key1=value1&key2=value2`?  But `.map` gives you back an array. What you want in this case can be `.reduce`

Comment: @nopole, thank you for the `reduce()`, I already have the `join()` function to convert the array into string that is more appropriated to my needs.

Comment: @Fifi try destructuring: `const [key,val] = Object.entries(obj)[i||0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem like you only want to print it out or access them:

`.map` changes an array to a different array, which doesn't seem like what you are looking for.

```js
var objs = [{ 'key1' : 'value1' }, { 'key2' : 'value2' }];

objs.forEach(obj => { 
  for (let p in obj) console.log(p, obj[p]); 
});
```

If you are looking for `key1=value1&key2=value2` as the answer and you know you only have 1 key and value in each object, then it is:

```js
let objs = [{ 'key1' : 'value1' }, { 'key2' : 'value2' }];

let s = objs.map(obj => `${Object.keys(obj)[0]}=${Object.values(obj)[0]}`).join("&");

console.log(s);
```

But you probably want to use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the params, making it:

```js
let objs = [{ 'key1' : 'value1 hello' }, { 'key2' : 'value2 & 3' }];

let s = objs.map(obj => `${encodeURIComponent(Object.keys(obj)[0])}=${(encodeURIComponent(Object.values(obj)[0]))}`).join("&");

console.log(s);
```

If your keys are all alphanumeric and underscore characters, then you shouldn't need to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the key.

Comment: Thank you, but the question is about the map() method. I know how to loop over an array.

Comment: @Fifi please see second part of answer

Comment: Yes, that it. Not as simple as I expected, but I guess this is the shortest syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{ 'key1' : 'value1' }, { 'key2' : 'value2' }];
obj.forEach(el => {
  for (var prop in el) {
    console.log(prop, el[prop])
  }
})

// results: 
// key1 value1
// key2 value2
```

Comment: I want to use the map method.

Comment: use .map insted of .foreach, it works also on this way

Comment: @Fifi But why? You still haven't told us yet what kind of array value you want to produce, and if you don't produce another array you should not use `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Not as clean as what @nopole answer, but this kind achieve what you want for a key, value object.

```js
var objs = [{ 'key1' : 'value1' }, { 'key2' : 'value2' }];

objs.forEach(obj => { 
  // loop over keys-and-values
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
});
```

Also this works for object with more than one key:

```js
var objs = [{ 'key1' : 'value1', "key2":"value2" }, { 'key3' : 'value3' }];

objs.forEach(obj => { 
  // loop over keys-and-values
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
});
```